# Why isn't yard showing private methods in rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, yard

I am generating documentation with Yard, but even when I've run `yardoc --private`, it is not showing documentation for private methods in the source.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have figured it out. Even if you generated the documentation with `yardoc --private`, you have to add `--private` line into the `.yardopts` file for it to show.